# UIPageViewController delegate not firing for landscape orientation

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, orientation, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a uipageviewcontroller to show some list of viewcontrollers.Everything is working fine in protrait ,all the delegate and datasources method are fired in the portrait mode.But if i rotate the device to landscape orientation the delegate methods are not fired.Say
    `- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers` is not fired.

Answer (score 1):

Every time the orientation changes you need to again set the view controller

```
WeightPageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:currentViewControllerIndex];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
[self.weightPageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPage
```